# python import problem

Tags: python

although there are many posts on the internet as well as some posts on stack overflow, I still want to ask about this nasty python "import" problem.

OK. so, the open source code organization is usually like this:

project/src/model.py;

project/test/testmodel.py

if I put the famous `__init__.py` in project directory and also in src/ and test/ subdirectories, 
and then put "from project.src import model" for the testmodel.py. 
it does not work! keep telling me that the Module named "project.src" is not found!

how can I solve the problem without changing the code structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the **parent** directory of `project/` on your pythonpath, rather than the project directory. If you add the project path itself, imports like `import project.src` will look for project/project/src.

Answer (score 3):

You shoud not add the project directory to your pythonpath but it's parent, e.g. imagine the setup

```
/home/user/develop/project/src/model
```

You'd add /home/user/develop to PYTHONPATH

If that still doesn't work, make sure you don't have a 'project.py' insite project/src/model.

Answer (score 0):

The directory where project is located is probably not in your python path.

Comment: I added the project directory into the pythonpath. the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a relative import (assuming Python 2.5+) from testmodel.py, like:

```
from ..src import model
```

However, this does not work if you're running testmodel.py as the main module.